# Map escape key to :q in vim in normal mode

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I use vim as a viewer in midnight commandder and I want to quickly view and close a file. How can I map the escape key to `:q` in normal mode so that vim exits only if nothing is changed?

Comment: Why not use an actual "viewer" instead of an editor?

Comment: Because it gives me much more capability such as configable code highlight. And I can edit the file in the case I like and exit with no pain if it is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

To do it for just the current `vim` session,
type the following commands (in `vim`).  (Spaces are added for clarity. 
Do not type a space except where I have indicated <kbd>Space</kbd>.)

> <kbd>:</kbd> 
>   <kbd>m</kbd> 
>   <kbd>a</kbd> 
>   <kbd>p</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Space</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Esc</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Space</kbd> 
>   <kbd>:</kbd> 
>   <kbd>q</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Enter</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Enter</kbd>

To do it for just the rest of the current Terminal session,
type the following commands (in Terminal; i.e., the shell). 
(Line break(s) are added for clarity.  Type the following all on one line;
do not type <kbd>Enter</kbd> except where I have indicated <kbd>Enter</kbd>.)

> <kbd>E</kbd> 
>   <kbd>X</kbd> 
>   <kbd>I</kbd> 
>   <kbd>N</kbd> 
>   <kbd>I</kbd> 
>   <kbd>T</kbd> 
>   <kbd>=</kbd>
>   <kbd>"</kbd> 
>   <kbd>:</kbd> 
>   <kbd>m</kbd> 
>   <kbd>a</kbd> 
>   <kbd>p</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Space</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Esc</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Space</kbd> 
>   <kbd>:</kbd> 
>   <kbd>q</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Enter</kbd> 
>   <kbd>"</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Enter</kbd>

and then

> `export EXINIT`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

To make the changes “permanent” (i.e., until you change the files back),
put the above commands (the `EXINIT="…"` and `export EXINIT`)
into your `.bash_profile` and/or `.bashrc`. 
(You can put them together on the same line, separating them with `;`. 
You may be able to shorten this by combining them into `export EXINIT="…"`.) 
This won’t take effect until you login again,
or possibly until you start a new shell,
unless you just type the `EXINIT` commands
or `source` the file into which you put the `EXINIT` commands.

**Note:** if you aren't using bash as your primary shell,
you may need to modify the above for your shell.

Alternatively, try putting the `:map …` command into your `.exrc` file.

---

In case this isn’t obvious,

```
:map string1 string2
```

(in `vi` / `vim`) creates a mapping (translation) so that,
when you type `string1` (in command mode),
the editor acts like you typed `string2`. 
And <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is the super-escape character
that tells both `vi` / `vim` and the shell
(in fact, probably *all* programs, or at least most of them)
that the following character is meant to be interpreted
as a literal textual character, and not as a control character. 
Note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
gives you a carriage return character, which is often displayed as `^M`;
but, in a `:map` `string2`,
that is interpreted as an <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks G-Man. The first approach works perfectly well (but is useless as you know). The second one does not work. I am on Mac OS. Do you have any idea why it's not working?

Comment: I followed the same procedure with `~/.exrc` file and it does not work as well.

Comment: @Oxy: I edited the answer to clarify possible misunderstanding.  I don’t know why it isn’t working.  Can you get other commands through into `vim` by any of those techniques?  For example, do you already have a `~/.exrc` whose contents are working?  If you type `export EXINIT=":map q jjjj"; vim some_file`, does (`q`) make your cursor go down four lines?  If you type `export EXINIT=":set list"; vim some_file`, does it show `$` at the ends of lines (and does it show tabs as `^I`)?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Weird!

Comment: Well, `vi` should be `vi` the world around, but OS X isn't Linux.  Try researching `vi` on OS X (start with `man vi`, and then search Super User, and then Google) to see whether it has some different way of letting you pass in initialization commands.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll comment here if I solved the issue.